# How can I debug authentication issue in a local webservice method call?

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

I have an ASP .NET webpage which calls an ASP.NET webservice existing on the same site. Both of them require integrated windows authentication.

I get the following error during invoke of the webservice method when I run my webpage:
"The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. "

I have no clue why it is failing. Is there a way to know which authentication protocol is being used from the website to invoke the webservice method, and why it is failing?

EDIT : As suggested, I downloaded auth diagnostics, and monitored it when i ran my webpage. Following is result:

AcceptSecurityContext
Package=NTLM Result=0x0 ContextAttr=0x12001c UserName= ClientName= ServerName=Result=0x0(Fail: context has ASC_RET_NULL_SESSION flag)
Main process: Finished, 1 issue detected

Comment: Can you post up your web.config so we can see the authentication configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through the Microsoft [Troubleshooting HTTP 401 errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273) article?

Answer (score 1):

How is IIS configured? Is it set up to use anonymous or Windows Auth? Also, what context is the app pool using? Perhaps the web is running under a context that doesn't have permissions to hit the web service?